# Pegando a Data da publicação pela API do facebook

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

Bom dia,

Eu estou implementando a APi do facebook, mas preciso que ele me traga alem da foto e da descrição da publicação, a data da publicação(Dia e Mês).

Alguem ja fez ou sabe, que pode me ajudar como fazer?
Grato!

@@Edit

A API já me traz as informações de data, com o created_time!

então dentro do Facebook.js

```
function dateByJsonToUTC(dateCurrent){
    var postDate = new Date(dateCurrent);
    var mes = postDate.getUTCMonth() + 1;
    var utcDate =   {
      'year' : postDate.getUTCFullYear(),
      'month' : postDate.getUTCMonth(),
      'mes' : transformDateNumberInDateString( postDate.getUTCMonth() + 1),
      'day' : postDate.getUTCDate(),
      'hour' : postDate.getUTCHours(),
      'minutes' : postDate.getUTCMinutes()
    }
    return utcDate;
}
```

onde estou setando as informações da data. Dentro do for, para pegar todos os posts da pagina, coloquei: `let date = dateByJsonToUTC( listPosts[i].created_time );`, onde eu consigo pegar as informações que eu queira da data, por exemplo **date.day**

Comment: Está obtendo via `/me/posts`? Salvo engano ele já retorna o `created_time`

Comment: Realmente, ele já me traz o created_time, já consegui resolver, muito obrigado! <3